# Create new Angular project - Package install failed

Tags: angular, macos, npm

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.8
Node: 10.16.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.8
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.8
@angular/cli                 8.3.8
@schematics/angular          8.3.8
@schematics/update           0.803.8
```

When I try to create a new project: `ng new projectName`, I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code ETARGET
>   npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular-devkit/architect@0.803.12
>   npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
>   npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
>   npm ERR! notarget 
>   npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@angular-devkit/build-angular'
>   npm ERR! notarget
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2019-10-21T08_48_20_226Z-debug.log
>   Package install failed, see above.

Here is the log file contains:

> 2488 verbose type version
>   2489 verbose stack @angular-devkit/architect: No matching version found for @angular-devkit/architect@0.803.12.
>   2489 verbose stack     at pickManifest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-pick-manifest/index.js:122:13)
>   2489 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/manifest.js:24:14
>   2489 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>   2489 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
>   2489 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
>   2489 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)
>   2489 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:142:12)
>   2489 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
>   2489 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
>   2489 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>   2489 verbose stack     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
>   2490 verbose cwd /Users/me/AngularLab/myWorkSpace/projectName
>   2491 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
>   2492 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--quiet"
>   2493 verbose node v12.13.0
>   2494 verbose npm  v6.12.0
>   2495 error code ETARGET
>   2496 error notarget No matching version found for @angular-devkit/architect@0.803.12.
>   2497 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
>   2497 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
>   2497 error notarget
>   2497 error notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@angular-devkit/build-angular'
>   2498 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Any idea please where I'am going wrong?

Comment: try re-installing angular/cli: npm uninstall @angular/cli -g, npm install @angular/cli -g

Comment: Didn't help. Error remains the same.

Comment: uninstall node.js and re-install again

Comment: @KiranMistry I did it. Unfortunately didn't help also. It's a strange/weird issue!

Comment: npm cache clean --force run this command

Comment: @KiranMistry Done. Error remains the same.

Comment: have u install npm..? if not then use this command `npm i npm-install` and re-install `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Comment: The issue has to do with the dependency of `@angular-devkit/architect@0.803.12`, as when I run: `ng --version`, I do have: `@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.8` which doesn't match the newest/latest version of: `@angular-devkit/architect`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201408/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-kiran-mistry).

Answer (score 0):

```
1.check node version
node -v

2.if not installed then follow the below 
Go to the Node.js Downloads page
Download Node.js for macOS by clicking the "Macintosh Installer" option
Run the downloaded Node.js .pkg Installer
Run the installer, including accepting the license, selecting the destination, and authenticating for the install.

3.check for npm
npm -v

4.install npm
npm install npm -g
```

Comment: This can not be the Fix as I have been doing it before.